# ROC Curves for Regression Output

Tags: regression, roc, tensorflow, auc

I am working on a broad machine learning-based problem, which can be approached in several different ways. Essentially, my training values are floats between 0.0 and 1.0, and I have approached this in two ways: A) treat it as a classification problem, calling values below 0.5 "class X" and above 0.5 "class Y", or B) treat it as a regression problem and try to predict the exact value between 0.0 and 1.0.

I have started testing both approaches using TensorFlow, but I would like to have a way to evaluate both and compare them.

In case A above, I have been using ROC curves/AUC to evaluate different parameters. In case B, I can calculate the correlation coefficient between the true and predicted values.

My question is: is there a better approach to standardize the evaluation and compare both cases? For example, is there a standard way to generate a ROC curve for the regression output in case B? (I assume this would mean setting some kind of threshold for distinguishing between "true" and "false"?)

Comment: "*broad machine learning-based problem*" is rather generic I am afraid. Can you please be a bit more specific? Similarly it seems that beta regression would be relevant for this response variable ("*floats between 0.0 and 1.0*"), have you considered it?

Comment: Yes, I tried to keep it generic for a few reasons. For one, I am planning to try many different approaches, and two, I think most of these can be adapted to generate the evaluation output I am asking about. But as an example, for case A I am trying both logistic regression and a feed-forward deep neural network approach, and case B I am trying a few different deep learning approaches. In all cases I would like something like a ROC curve to evaluate the output across all approaches. Beta regression sounds like a great idea for this training data, I will look into it, thanks!